# Im using a timer for my game and would like to show the current score and save the high score. How would I do this?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

The timer starts at zero and goes up. The more time you last the higher the score. How would I show the current score and save the high score with a timer? I got the timer to work but Im stuck at this problem. Im in spritekit and in Swift! Thanks!

```
func updateTimer() {

    fractions += 1
    if fractions == 100 {

        seconds += 1
        fractions = 0
    }

    if seconds == 60 {

        minutes += 1
        seconds = 0
    }

    let fractionsString = fractions > 9 ? "\(fractions)" : "0\(fractions)"
    let secondsString = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    let minutesString = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"


    timerString = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString).\(fractionsString)"
    countUpLabel.text = timerString

}

 //EDIT..............

  func saveHighScore() {

    let defaults=NSUserDefaults()


    let highscore=defaults.integerForKey("highscore")


    if(timerString > highscore)
    {
        defaults.setInteger(timerString, forKey: "highscore")
    }
    let highscoreshow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

    endOfGameHighScoreLabel.text = String(highscoreshow)


    }
```

Comment: It is simpler to just keep an incrementing count of seconds (or hundredths of seconds) and do the integer division to get the minutes/seconds/100ths when required for display. Your code looks like it should show the current score (or time) what exactly is your question

Comment: @Paulw11 The timer works correctly. The problem is that when the game is over I want to display the current score and then save the score if its higher than the current score.

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults to persist the score value.  Again this will be easier if you just store a single integer

Comment: I got the current score to show but Im getting an error trying to save the highscore. I get this error binary operator > cannot be applied to operands of type String and Int. Im gonna update the question so you could see what i did @Paulw11

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you get what Im trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to store and increment the three separate values, it is simpler to store a single integer, score, and then calculate the separate value each time for display.

Then to compare and save your high score it is a simple integer comparison.

```
func updateTimer() {
    self.score++
    countUpLabel.text=self.timeStringForScore(self.score)
}


func timeStringForScore(score:Int) -> String {
    let minutes:Int=score/6000;
    let seconds:Int=(score-minutes*6000)/100
    let fractions:Int = score-minutes*6000-seconds*100
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds,fractions)
}

func saveHighScore() {  
    let defaults=NSUserDefaults()
    let highscore=defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
    if(self.score > highscore)
    {
        defaults.setInteger(self.score, forKey: "highscore")
    }

    endOfGameHighScoreLabel.text = self.timeStringForScore(highscore)
}
```